# Angular - Common Component making different API calls on OnInit

Tags: angular, service, routes, components

I have a use case in which two different routes have almost completely similar view. The way to go(in my understanding) is to route to the same component thus reusing them. The component is basically showing a list of items which are clickable.
**The only problem is** that I have to make calls to different API on the OnInit of the same component depending on the current route. And on the click of those list items, I have to route to different components. For Example in path 'todo' on click of items routing is like:

```
path: 'todo',
            component: UserDesktopMainComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: ':empLoginId/:formId',
                    component: EvaluationFormComponent
                },
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: EmptyComponentComponent
                },

                {
                    path: '**',
                    redirectTo: ''
                }
            ]
```

And from path 'history'

```
path: 'history',
            component: HistoryDesktopComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: ':empLoginId',
                    component: EvaluationDetailsComponent
                },
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: EmptyComponentComponent
                },

                {
                    path: '**',
                    redirectTo: ''
                }
            ]
```

The solution I have in mind is to check for the current route onInit before making calls via either the route snapshot or pass keywords in the data part of the route. Then in service, I can pass that particular keyword from component and call the API accordingly(I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this). For the routing on click, I can call a component function which would navigateByURL based on the current route. Currently, in the template, I'm routing like:

```
<a *ngFor="let emp of employeeDisplayList" routerLink="{{'/todo/'+emp.employee.loginId+'/'+emp.evaluationFormMappingId}}"</a>
```

which probably won't let me route the way I want.

I might be missing something very basic concept wise here, or this may be a design pattern question. **What I would like to know is that if there's a better, elegant way to solve all the above questions mentioned which will basically reuse the component**. I don't want to copy the same code from one component to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand this issue, you want a list of clickable items on two pages - but the urls are built differently.

---

Make a new component!

In Typescript/Javascript functions are objects, so we can use them as input parameters to components.

---

clickable-list.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-clickable-list',
    templateUrl: './clickable-list.html',
    styleUrls: ['./clickable-list.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ClickableListComponent<T> {
    @Input()
    public items: T[];

    @Input()
    public getUrl: (item: T) => string;

    constructor(){}
}
```

clickable-list.html

```
<div>
    <a *ngFor="let item of items" [routerLink]="getUrl(item)"</a>
</div>
```

UserDesktopMainComponent (HTML)

```
<my-clickable-list [items]="employeeDisplayList" [getUrl]="getTodoUrl"></my-clickable-list>
```

UserDesktopMainComponent (TS)

```
public getTodoUrl(emp: WhateverTypeThisIsSupposedToBe) {
    return "/todo/" + emp.employee.loginId + "/" + emp.evaluationFormMappingId;
}
```

HistoryDesktopComponent (HTML)

```
<my-clickable-list [items]="employeeDisplayList" [getUrl]="getHistoryUrl"></my-clickable-list>
```

HistoryDesktopComponent (TS)

```
public getHistoryUrl(emp: WhateverTypeThisIsSupposedToBe) {
    return "/history/" + emp.employee.loginId;
}
```

Comment: I kind of understand your answer. So just to clarify, the use-case is like the UserDesktopMainComponent is the main component where I need to dynamically route to either a todo component or history component(these two are the similar component I mentioned in my question). So the clickable component that you have created should be injected into history component as you've done and similarly I'll create a todo component and insert the clickable component in it, and then route to these two components in my user UserDesktopMainComponent depending on the URL. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that was what you're looking for. I assumed you wanted UserDesktopMain to route to EvaluationForm and HistoryDesktop to route to EvaluationDetailsComponent.
You may not need a new component for what you describe, you might be able to use a similar strategy to this answer - have `routerLink` bind to a function, then apply whatever logic you need to determine if the link should go to ToDo or History